# bxslider goToSlide() while skipping the slides inbetween

Tags: jquery, bxslider

Is it possible to use goToSlide() method without animating through the slides inbetween?

E.g. I want to go directly from slide 1 to slide 5, skipping the animation through slides 2 to 4.

I was wondering if there is any option for it (or alternatively a css hack).

Here's my code:

```
var slider = $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
    pager: false,
    controls: false,
    auto: false,
    touchEnabled: false
});

$('.gotoslide5').click(function() {
    slider.goToSlide(5);
});
```

JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/1n5wfm3q/1

Answer (score 1):

this is kind of a hack, if you set the speed to `1` the animation becomes so fast it isn't visible.

```
var slider = $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
    pager: false,
    controls: true,
    auto: false,
    touchEnabled: false
});



    $('.gotoslide5').click(function() {
        setToSlide(2);
    });

   var setToSlide = function(slideIndex){
                    var width = $('.bxslider').find('li').width()
           slider.css('transform','translate3d(-'+(width*slideIndex)+'px, 0px, 0px)')
    }


        $('.gotoslide5').click(function() {
            slider.goToSlide(5);
        });
```

updated fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/riazxrazor/1n5wfm3q/3/

Comment: Well, good solution, but not really a solution (I actually would like to keep the animation) :)

Comment: Many thanks! It's a clever approach I think, but still not really "moving" from slide 1 to 5 is it?